# Using Formik in NextJs 13

Tags: forms, validation, formik, next.js13

I am trying to use Formik in NextJs 13 with the new router. I am quite convinece my code is correct, but, maybe I got something wrong, because clicking on the login button only redirects the page with the form data appended to the url like an API get request.

My code:

```
'use client'

import Button from "@/components/Buttons";
import Input from "@/components/Inputs";
import AuthLayout from "@/layouts/AuthLayout";
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import { object, string } from "yup";

export default function Home() {

  const handleLogin = async (values: any) => {
    console.log('values: ', values);
  };

  const validationSchema = object().shape({
    phone: string().required('Phone is required'),
  });

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      phone: '',
    },
    validationSchema: validationSchema,
    onSubmit: handleLogin
  })

  return (
    <AuthLayout className="md:max-w-md">
      <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
        <Input.Primary
          type='text'
          name='phone'
          id='phone'
          placeholder='Enter Phone'
          wrapperStyle='!p-2'
          value={formik.values.phone}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
          error={!!formik.errors.phone}
          autoComplete='tel'
        />

        <Button.Primary
          className='w-full'
          onClick={handleLogin}
          type='submit'>
          Login
        </Button.Primary>
      </form>
    </AuthLayout>
  )
}
```

My setup:

```
{
  "name": "lender",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "formik": "^2.4.5",
    "next": "13.5.6",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "yup": "^1.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

I have tried the current code as attached above, I have tried using the `<Formik ></Formit>` component instead of the `useFormik` hook.

I have also tried using it the way I do in my React Native projects, that's without the `<form>` element.

In each of these cases, it is either the button click returns NOTHING or it just do the redirect.

Thank you for your help.